# Dynamic instruction trace for Android Apps

Tags: android, trace

I want to generate the dynamic instruction trace of Android Apps (Just like for a basic hello world C program, I am able to generate the instruction trace using the tools like [Dynamorio](https://dynamorio.org/), [pintool](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool.html)).

I want to know at runtime, what are the address of the instruction which are getting executed? Is anyone aware of any existing tool which can help me in this?

I found out that there are existing tools like Dynamorio (support for Linux, Windows is there but for Android's ART environment, they are not), Pin tool (the last Android version they were supporting is the Icecream).

I also tried using https://perfetto.dev/ but they seem to capture the device activity.

In that, if I want to generate the dynamic instruction trace of Android Apps, I am unable to do so.

Is anyone aware of any tool which seems to generate the dynamic instruction trace for Android Apps?

Any response from your side will be highly appreciated and will help in my project.